# MS Excel changes \n with \r

Tags: excel, lf

I have CSV file with line ending character equal to "\n". When I edit it and hit save, I get alert "Some features in your workook might be lost if you save it as CSV". I tried with both Yes and No, and in both cases it changes line endings in file to \r. I use MS Excel on Win7.

How it is possible, why doesn't it keep \n or add \r\n which is CRLF for Windows?

Comment: Simply because `\r\n` is the standard end of line for text files in Windows?

Comment: Which Excel Version are you using?